# VBA Intermittent ByRef Error - Format function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm newer to VBA than VB. I've had circumstances while using ADO.NET where the project gets corrupted and you, for lack of a better word, break your project. This procedure is from a larger project that pulls together automated reports for call center agent performance and specifically will find the last seven days results then delete any other values within that range to be calculated by another sheet in the workbook.

Backstory: I've used this procedure for about three weeks with no issue. One day, I was running my reports and got a ByRef error for the default Format function, specifically the variable "d". Tried a bunch of stuff to rewrite around the format function in case the syntax was a little off: Format([string], "Short Date"), Format([date], "Short Date"), Format([date], "mmddyyyy"), and Format([string], "mmddyyyy") all result in ByRef Error. I wish there was a simple .toshortdatestring like VB.NET. Tried creating my own format function as well to no avail.

However, when I paste all of my code - EXACTLY - into one of my backups, the ByRef error goes away.... Thought I just broke that workbook, so I copied and pasted all of my modules into my back up and went on my merry way. A week later, running my reports again, I get the same ByRef error at the Format function, highlighting the variable d. Any thoughts as to why this keeps happening??  Thanks in advance!!

Excel 2013 - file size approx 7 MB - 28 sheets - 14 with multiple countifs/sumifs to pull specific agent stats from the raw data - nothing fancy.

```
Sub Last7Days(lastcolumn As String, wksht As Worksheet, width As Integer, datasheet As String)


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim column As Long
Set sht = wksht

Dim rng As Range, inclusiveRange As Range
Dim startDate As Long, endDate As Long


column = 1
Dim d As Date



d = DateAdd("d", -7, Now)

d = Format(d, "Short Date")

Dim startdatestring As String


startdatestring = CStr(d)

Dim enddatestring As String

wksht.Activate
Call LastRowInA

Range("a" & LastRowInA).Select
enddatestring = CStr(ActiveCell.value)



startDate = DateValue(startdatestring)
endDate = DateValue(enddatestring)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wksht.Activate
    sht.Cells(1, column).AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd _
            , Criteria2:="<=" & endDate


    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, column), sht.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row, column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False

    If rng.Address = sht.Cells(1, column).Address Then



        MsgBox Format(startDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & Format(endDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "No instances of the date range exist"

    Else

    Set inclusiveRange = sht.Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Count, width))

        inclusiveRange.Select
        Selection.Cut
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(datasheet).Range("a2")
        Dim Start As String

        Dim size As Long
        'Set size = Nothing
        Start = "A" & (rng.Count + 1)
        size = Range("a" & rng.Count, Range("a" & rng.Count).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
       Range("a" & (rng.Count + 1) & ":I675000").Select
       Selection.Clear



    End If
Dim LastDateValue As String

LastDateValue = enddatestring


startdate1 = DateValue(LastDateValue)
endDate1 = DateValue(LastDateValue)

Dim testDate As Date
Dim testDateInteger As Integer
testDate = startdate1
testDateInteger = Weekday(testDate)

If testDateInteger = 2 Then


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wksht.Activate
    sht.Cells(1, column).AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=">=" & startdate1, Operator:=xlAnd _
        , Criteria2:="<=" & endDate1


    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, column), sht.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row, column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False


    Set inclusiveRange1 = sht.Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Count, width))

        inclusiveRange1.Select
        Selection.Clear
  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `d = Format(d, "Short Date")`? It seems very odd to format a date and store it back into a date variable instead of a string variable.

Comment: Not sure how to block code out in replies... Sorry, that looks messy

Comment: Use the tick mark below the tilde before and after your code in comments. Usually above the tab key.

Comment: Just using the startdatestring results in the same ByRef error on d in the Format function  `Dim d As Date
Dim startdatestring As String
d = DateAdd("d", -7, Now)
startdatestring = Format(d, "Short Date")`

Comment: Hmm. If I drop the code in your comment into a VBA Sub in Excel, it works. I get no errors and a startdatestring value of 7/21/2014. Seems like the problem might be outside of that code block. That subset of the code looks correct.

Comment: I use `Format()` all the time, so I'm going to place the blame on `DateAdd` even though I have no evidence that it's the culprit (or any reason to believe that it should be). Get rid of DateAdd and use `d = Now - 7` and see how long it goes before you get the error again.

Comment: Is LastRowInA a Sub or a Function or a Variable?? `Call LastRowInA` uses it like a Sub. `Range("a" & LastRowInA).Select` uses it like a Function or a Variable.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of my point. It's valid code. But after I run my script a few times it breaks at this point and gives the ByRef error. What I have to do to fix it is open my backup workbook and copy all of my updates to it. Add the suffix of BROKEN to the file name and am getting a boneyard starting to pile up. Maybe some sort of an overflow issue. But there shouldn't be any permanent memory allocated to excel workbooks. Really strange.

Comment: @DickKusleika I use DateAdd all the time. His syntax matches everything I've ever seen or done. I can't find a reasonable reason to believe that DateAdd is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, LastRowInA is a function and should be able to be used as a value, since it returns a value. At least that's my understanding of how functions operate in VBA.... VBA is a little wonky to what I'm used to with VB.NET, I'm pretty much all self taught from forums... `Function LastRowInA() As Long
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
  LastRowInA = LastRow

End Function`

Comment: BTW still getting ByRef with `d = Now - 7` the Format function isn't liking it. It seems like it wants it in a different data type but i've tried all the iterations that would make sense.

Comment: Just an update... I've reverted to my backup and it's processing this whole module correctly. But, we already knew that the code is valid.... That's really the point of my question. What could cause the code to break at this point. Maybe it's the weakest link or the most memory intensive... Anybody familiar with the memory allocation that VBA uses and how to manage it?

Comment: Here are the first explanations off the top of my head. First, you can try Open and Repair (drop down in Open dialog). Secondly, hit Ctrl+End on each worksheet and see if any of those are much further down the sheet than you expect. Third, Excel tends to cache old versions in the file. This creates a lot of bloat over time. You can try to just migrate your data and code to a new workbook, save the new file, see if the file size is smaller, and check whether everything works now. I've actually been very successful with Option 3 in the past.

Comment: Dang, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. There's got to be a way to manage the memory in VBA.

Comment: Well there's only so much memory management to do in relatively standard VBA calls. It's good practice to set objects like Worksheet and Range to Nothing when they are no longer in use but Excel is supposed to do that for you when the variable leaves scope so leaving those lines out shouldn't create any memory bloat based on local variables once the Sub finishes. You can always try eliminating the Activate and Select lines as that causes lots of problems but I 'm not sure if that will help you here. Select is an interface function that is not very useful in VBA Subs. I would try that.

Comment: Are you at a point where it will consistently throw an error every time you run the procedure? If so, there are some alternatives I'd be curious to have you test.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff I agree, just grasping at straws here. Donovin Well, we can rule that out then. I noticed that some of your variables weren't declared. It shouldn't be the cause of your problems, but you might consider putting Option Explicit at the top of your modules. If you have sample data available, I could run it on my end and see if I can make it fail.

Comment: here's an idea for a temp fix, create code that will move your modules automatically to one of your back ups. Then, whenever an error pops up, make your error handler run the code that will migrate everything to a backup. It's not pretty, but it's cool in its own way :D Here is some starter code: ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(2).Export(YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE)

Comment: Awesome. I'll give that a shot. I did try option explicit while working on this last broken workbook to make sure that the Format function was not letting me get away with funky output data types...  @Blackhawk I have two broken files that will consistently throw errors, so I'm game to try whatever.

Comment: I'm in the early stages of learning VBA syntax, so I'm curious what variables don't seem like they are declared. Based on what I've read all of the arguments of the procedure don't need to be declared and if you use set you don't have to manually declare the variable. If I'm off base, I'd love to get some feedback. VBA is definitely a different bird than VB.NET, so I'll take all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what is going on, it's true, but odds are if it is a compiler bug as the conversation in the comments indicates, it's probably hyper-specific to the exact usage of functions you have in your code.  To fix it, you could try rewriting the same code logic a slightly different way.  Assuming that your error is with the following section of code, I can suggest a couple things and based on how Excel reacts to those there could be other things to try.

```
Dim d As Date
d = DateAdd("d", -7, Now)
d = Format(d, "Short Date")
Dim startdatestring As String
startdatestring = CStr(d)
```

1. Try adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module of code. This causes VBA to force you to explicitly `Dim` all your variables and while it probably won't solve your specific issue, it's good programming practice and it may reveal other issues with your code that you can fix and get out of the way.
2. Try rewriting the section of code without the variable `d`.

   ```
   Dim startdatestring As String
   startdatestring = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Now), "Short Date")
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something that I did try. After the original ByRef error and the project "breaks" it will error on valid code in different ways. After I moved to this more streamlined argument I started to get: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment errors. It's really strange. The code works completely and properly a few times (probably 25-30 executions), then breaks down at this procedure.

Comment: Well I'm kind of stumped then - have you tried running the same Excel workbook on a different computer for comparison?

Comment: Yes, my desk computer was recently replaced. First break was on the old one and then it happened again a couple of days ago... This whole thing is just crazy. That's why I'm posting here... I can't think of anything that would cause this to continue to happen.

Comment: To clarify, my computer was replaced for faster performance - not due to failure.