# Clear memory allocation Excel VBA - Stack - Memory - Permanent Memory Allocation

Tags: vba, excel, memory-management, stack

I have a workbook that's around 7 MB and will break about every few weeks. This is my post previously.

[VBA Intermittent ByRef Error - Format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002720/vba-intermittent-byref-error-format-function?noredirect=1#comment38876697_25002720)

After a little group effort, it looks like the issue might be with excel's memory allocation. It seems to start throwing errors on valid code. Usually a ByRef. It may be a temporary stack issue, but it seems more permanent, since it's occurs after several runs. Any ideas how to manage excel's auto backup or other permanent allocation of memory? Long story short, I'm having to copy and paste my new code into backups every couple of weeks and I think that's a bit silly. I'm sure there's a better way to manage that with the help of the gurus on here at SO. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to ask a question twice on here. Just add an edit to the original question.

Comment: @Ella this is a second, specific and separate question, I think he's good.

Comment: @Blackhawk thanks! I kind of want to know the answer so I didn't want it to get downvoted.

Comment: @Ella I see what you mean though - if this question is going to stand on its own, the OP should probably remove most of the mentions of the previous question.

Comment: Why not keep your VBA code in a separate file from your data? Wouldn't that remove the copy + pasting

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the dupe post. Wasn't sure if I'd get a some dirty internet stares about it, but I felt this was a new question that would be better understood with a background.... Alter, that's an awesome question. I didn't know storing code in a seperate file was possible. I've tried to trim of the bulk as I can by separating the report into three files. The source files that I get emailed to me, I just drop them in a folder (they always have the same file name).

Comment: The intermediate workbook, which has all of the command code, a data sheet to hold the raw data from the source sheet and a corresponding formula sheet which processes the raw data (countifs/sumifs). Then there is an output file that just has formatting, which is where the computed data are pasted. It's kind of a monster of a process, because almost everything is variable so it has to be scalable and allow for nulls..... How would you reach the code if it were stored in a separate file, I'm assuming you mean another xlsm...